# How to link homebrew installed python3.x version to python3 command?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew, upgrade

I had on OSX High Sierra versions 2.7 and 3.6 and correspondingly `pip` and `pip3` installed. The terminal commands `python` and `pip` were linked to Python2 while `python3` and `pip3` to python3`

I upgraded my Python3 version with `homebrew`. The installation was successful but now I have to link the command for python3. `homebrew` suggests:

> Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1...
>
> Error: Could not symlink Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
>
> Target /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
>   is a symlink belonging to python@2. You can unlink it:
>
> brew unlink python@2
>
> To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
>
> brew link --overwrite python
>
> To list all files that would be deleted:
>
> brew link --overwrite --dry-run python

However this would link python3 to `python` terminal command while I want a separate `python3` and `pip3` commands.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

> However this would link python3 to `python` terminal command

That’s not true. Homebrew links `python` to either its own Python 2 or the system Python. It never links it to Python 3:

> Homebrew provides one formula for Python 3.x (python) and another for Python 2.7.x (python@2).
>
> The executables are organised as follows so that Python 2 and Python 3 can both be installed without conflict:
>
> - python3 points to Homebrew’s Python 3.x (if installed)
> - python2 points to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x (if installed)
> - **python points to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x (if installed) otherwise the macOS system Python**. Check out brew info python if you wish to add Homebrew’s 3.x python to your PATH.
> - pip3 points to Homebrew’s Python 3.x’s pip (if installed)
> - pip and pip2 point to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x’s pip (if installed)

Emphasis mine. Source: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python#python-3x-or-python-2x

You should thus be fine linking `python@3`. If you can’t do so, you can add `$(brew --prefix python)/bin` to your `PATH` to get all `python3` and similar binaries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the end I solved my problem installing `Python3` directly from the official website https://www.python.org/downloads/.